# xattr/extended attributes not settable for file in /tmp while in $home on same mount works fine

Tags: linux, file-attributes, xattr, tmpfs

I am playing with extended file attributes under Linux/Fedora and I am currently stumbling a bit since I cannot add/change attributes for files in `/tmp` while in my home it is working fine - while both paths are on the same mount point, i.e.,

```
/dev/mapper/fedora-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
```

for example, I can successful add and retrieve a attribute for files in my home directory, e.g.,

```
> setfattr -n user.test.md5 -v 58d8e4cd0e60facf386838cbe8b11767 ~/foo.bar
> getfattr -n user.test.md5 ~/foo.bar 
  # file: foo.bar
  user.test.md5="58d8e4cd0e60facf386838cbe8b11767"
```

However, the same fails for the same file in `/tmp`.

```
> cp ~/foo.bar /tmp/foo.bar
> setfattr -n user.test.md5 -v 58d8e4cd0e60facf386838cbe8b11767 /tmp/foo.bar 
  setfattr: /tmp/foo.bar: Operation not supported
```

I assumed, that the support for extended attributes only depends on the filesystem mounted 'correctly' with xattr support. However, it seems also be directory(??) dependent and I wonder, what prevents me from setting extended attributes in /tmp and how I can change it? (It seems not to be SELinux related - at least I did not find anything in the audit logs.)

Comment: Are you *sure* that `/home` and `/tmp` are both part of `/`? They're quite often not... In particular, `/tmp` might be a `tmpfs` file system, which may not support the extended attributes you're interested in...

Comment: @twalberg you are right! I had naively not properly checked, how /tmp is actually mounted but assumed from my inital setup

tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,seclabel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/tmp was not as I naively assumed mounted plainly but is mounted as tmpfs, that apparently does not support extended attributes

> tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,seclabel)

Thanks to twalberg!

Answer (score 5):

**tmpfs** can support extended attributes if you enable [`CONFIG_TMPFS_XATTR`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/fs/Kconfig?h=v5.9.3#n189) in the kernel config.
As of version 5.9.3 this enables support only for the `trusted.*` and `security.*` namespaces, so your `setfattr -n user.test.md5` command would still fail.